# How to remove a CSS attribute from an SCSS file?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have a CSS file that gets created from a custom SCSS that imports [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [AdminLte](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) and does just a few changes. The transpiled file includes the following:

```
.card-header::after,
.card-body::after,
.card-footer::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
```

Is it possible to remove the attribute `content` from the transpiled CSS file from within the SCSS file?

Comment: After compiling run regex replace. But without `content: "";` whole rule will lose it's purpose as pseudo elements needs to have defined `content:` in order to work

Comment: Could you describe a bit more why you need to do this, as you might as well delete all that code if you delete the content CSS property (BTW it's a property, not an attribute).

Comment: You could always override it in your own css with : `content: unset!important`